# Оптимизация кода c# с большими числами (long)

Tags: c#, алгоритм, оптимизация, list, производительность

Задача следующая: пользователью дают последовательность чисел от 1 до n, мы проверяем может ли произведение двух чисел из последовательности равняться сумме всех чисел последовательности не считая эти 2 числа.
Например: ряд от 1 до n, где n = 26. 
Произведение чисел 15 и 21 равно сумме всех чисел не считая 21 и 15.
Вот код:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class RemovedNumbers
{
    public static int Sum(long n)
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(int i =1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            sum+=i;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static List<int[]> removNb(long n)
    {
        int sum=Sum(n); 
        List <int[]> list = new List<int []>();
        int i,j;
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
            {
                if(i*j == sum-(i+j))
                {
                    list.Add(new int [] {i,j});
                    list.Add(new int [] {j,i});
                    return list;
                }
            }
        }

        return list; 
    }
}
```

Код выполняется за 0.015 секунд, нужно оптимизировать до 0.008, что посоветуете ?

Comment: Посоветую не использовать компиляцию в байткод, когда речь идет о выжимании миллисекунд

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: JIT-компилятор вполне себе компилирует этот байткод в нативный. Но вообще-то решать лучше не выжиманием тактов, а правкой алгоритма.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В двойном цикле вы дважды пробегаете все пары чисел (поскольку у вас может быть и `i > j` и `i < j`).
Поэтому вы легко можете удвоить скорость.

Вместо:

```
int i,j;
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Запишите:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Плюс, как правильно указал @pavel, сумму натурального ряда разумнее вычислять не в цикле, а по формуле:

```
int sum = n * (n + 1) / 2;
```

Comment: Деление на побитовый сдвиг разумнее заменить.

Comment: @justyx Во-первых, при включенной оптимизации, этим должен заниматься компилятор. Во-вторых, эта операция в приведенном коде - разовая. Не думаю, что существуют условия, при которых вы сможете заметить различия по времени выполнения даже без включенной оптимизации.

Answer (score 1):

Ну хотя бы так могу посоветовать: (для N = 1) не работает.

```
 const int N = 26;
 int r;
 int sum = N*(N+1)/2;
 for (int i=N/2;i<=N;i++)
    if ( (sum - i) % (i+1) == 0) 
        if ( (r = (sum - i) / (i+1) ) <= N)
            // {i,r} ответ
```

Можно дальше чуть подумать в этом направлении.

А причём тут большие числа? Наоборот все числа меньше 1000.

Кстати если ограничения на N небольшие, то есть смысл предпросчитать всё заранее

Answer (score 0):

Увы, не знаком с C#. Но - как минимум достаточно проверять числа, большие `n/2` и до `n+1`, в качестве делителей `n(n+1)/2-1` - тогда первое число на единицу меньше, ну, а второе понятно... Получаем как минимум `O(n)` вместо `O(n^2)`.

На C++ это выглядит так:

```
bool check(int n, int&k, int&m)
{
    int s = n*(n+1)/2 + 1;

    for(m = n/2 + 1; m <= n + 1; ++m)
        if (s%m == 0)
        {
            k = (n*(n+1)+2)/2/m-1;
            if (k == m-1) continue;
            m--;
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

Как я понимаю, числа не должны быть одинаковы? типа, 1+2+3+4+5 = 15, 15-6 = 9, 9 = 3*3 - не годится?